# Implicit Euler for stiff equation

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, differential-equations, numerical-integration

Problem: solve stiff different equation 
Method: implicit Euler
Plan: I calculate next 'y' by solvin non-linear equation use secant mehod. My function is `dy/dx = sin(x+y)`

There is right solution . I used newton method

main.m

```
h=0.01;
x(1)=0;
y_expl(1)=0;  
y_impl(1)=0+h;  
dy(1)=0;
eps=1.0e-6;

for i=1:1000

    x(i+1)=x(i)+h;

    y_impl(i+1)=newton(x(i),y_impl(i),y_impl(i));

    y_expl(i+1)=y_expl(i)+h*f(x(i),y_expl(i));

end

plot(x,y_impl,'r',x,y_expl,'b')
legend('Implicit Euler','Explicit Euler');
```

newton.m

```
function [ yn ] = newton( x,y,yi )

    eps=1.0e-6;
    err=1;
    step=0;
    step_max=100;
    h=0.01;
    xn=x+h;

    while (err > eps) && (step < step_max)

        step=step+1;

        yn=y-(F(xn,y,yi,h))/(J(xn,y,h));

        err=abs(y-yn)/(abs(yn)+1.0e-10);

        y=yn;

    end

end
```

f.m

```
function [ res ] = f( x,y )

res = sin(x+y);

end
```

G.m

```
function [ res ] = J( xn,y,h )

res = h*f(xn,y)-1;

end
```

F.m

```
function [ res ] = F( a,y,yn,h )

res = h*f(a,y)-y+yn;

end
```

Thank for attention

Comment: It's hard to try solving an error, if you don't tell us what error or problem you have.

Comment: Added : Error: all 'y' are zero

Comment: It's recommended that you put your code in the question, so it's still visible if e.g. GitHub goes down.

Comment: I add code . Thank for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you should not be solving `F(x,y)=0` but the equation resulting from the implicit Euler step `y=y0+h*F(x,y)`. Thus define

```
function [res] = G(x,y,y0,h)
    res = y - y0 - h*F(x,y)
end
```

and use the Newton or secant method for `G`.

---

General code critique:

- There is no `x(0)` in matlab.
- implicit Euler is a one-step method, no need to initialize for indices 2 and 3.
- The iteration for the x values is `x(i+1)=x(i)+h`

---

In the secant method: Known values are `x0=x(i)`, `y0=y(i)` and `h`.

- Needed before starting the loop are `x1=x0+h` and an initial value for `y1`. This can be taken as the result of an explicit Euler step, `y1=y0+h*F(x0,y0)` as predictor. The secant method serves as corrector.
- It makes the code more readable if the values of `G` are computed separately. Note that in `G(x1,y,y0,h)` the variable is `y` and the others are fixed parameters. Thus compute `G0=G(x1,y0,y0,h)` and `G1=G(x1,y1,y0,h)` for the secant formula `y2=y1-G1*(y1-y0)/(G1-G0)` or more symmetric `y2=(y0*G1-y1*G0)/(G1-G0)`.
- In principle you could use a generic secant method with interface `secant(func, a, b, tol)` by calling

  ```
  x(i+1) = x(i)+h;
  y(i+1) = secant(@(y) G(x(i+1),y,y(i),h), y(i), y(i)+h*F(x(i),y(i)), delt)
  ```

Comment: Could you help me with that? Exactly with secant.m . I don't understand how to write it for G.

Comment: I rewrote my code with your advice but it still not work.

Comment: There is so much wrong in the general philosophy,... I add a section about that.

Comment: Thank you, I rewrote my code with and it is worked now. I still have one question . : Is there is solution for system of equations?

Comment: Yes, there are Newton-like resp. quasi-Newton methods for systems, like the Broyden and adjoint Broyden method that extend the idea of the secant method to systems. Or one uses the exact or approximate Jacobian for Newton's method.